# Mouseenter event occurs multiple times even if i try to prevent it

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

Here is how it is supposed to work => [Normal behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eeJw.gif)

1) The event (mouseenter) is not supposed to fire after the latest likers box is created and is still open.
2) I have an event (mouseleave) on the latest likers box(NOT on the likes themselves).

BUT when i hover(mouseenter the first time) really fast the event occures many times and every time recreates the latest likers box(it shouldn't happen). =>
[Actual problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73z3H.gif)

```
$('.statuses_mbody').on('mouseenter',
'.status_likes, .reply_likes',function (e) {
  //capture the main data(not displayed for simplicity).
  //send ajax request.
  //here is code that checks the state of the box(closed,opened)
  //get data back from server and display them.
});
```

I have seen and tried many pieces of code over the internet,but still i cannot find a solution on this.

Comment: As you move the mouse pointer fast in that place, may be the pointer going out of the div and then again enters in the div and thus it's fire multiple times. You can add a flag when you're doing the ajax call. So until you get ajax success any other mouse enter will not call the ajax.

Comment: i upload again the first gif and i explained some things.

Comment: one method really does not help although it stops the repeated events at the beginning but then the event can not be triggered again :(

Comment: I used hoverIntent http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html and the problem now is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it check to see if the event is already in progress, I would probably do it like this:

```
$('.statuses_mbody').each(function() {
    $(this).one('mouseenter', '.status_likes, .reply_likes',function (e) {
    if ($(this).data('in-progress')) { return }
    $(this).data('in-progress', true)
    $.ajax(/* whatever */)
        .done(function() { /*whatever*/ })
        .always(function() {
            $(this).data('in-progress', false);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseenter` event will fire each time you enter the elements linked to this event ! 
Here is the description of the event:

> Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

Maybe you want `one()` event ?